# errors streamingvideoprovider.com with ogone payment

Tags: php

i run a website where i sell videos from streamingvideoprovider.com platform ( pay per view option ) using  ogone custom payment gateaway.

The payment process is ok but after the payment the redirection tells me "the payment verification is taking longer than expected".

How can i solve it and how can i send email ( with ticket ) to the buyer ??

i read the api developer and it's said i must call  ppv_confirm function but i don't know where to call the ppv_confirm function in my script.
Can youy help me thanks.

******** This is my custom payment form for ogone *************

```
<?php
function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max) {
    $range = $max - $min;
    if ($range < 0) return $min; // not so random...
    $log = log($range, 2);
    $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
    $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
    $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
    do {
        $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
        $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
    } while ($rnd >= $range);
    return $min + $rnd;
}

function getToken($length){
$token = "";
$codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
    $token .= $codeAlphabet[crypto_rand_secure(0,strlen($codeAlphabet))];
}
return $token;
}

/*  POST VALUES RECEIVED FROM www.streamingvideoprovider.com

    $_POST = array ( 
    [item_name] => Video ticket for: PLASTIC SURGERY
    [item_number] => 485485 
    [order_key] => d8193ytvr 
    [amount] => 15 
    [quantity] => 1 
    [return] => http://www.streamingvideoprovider.com/ppv_index.php?l=ppv_order&a=payment_overlay_success 
    [cancel] => http://www.streamingvideoprovider.com/ppv_index.php?l=ppv_order&a=payment_overlay_cancel 
    [currency] => EUR 
)*/

$ogone_SHA = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$ogone_PSPID = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$ogone_ORDERID = getToken(40); 
$ogone_AMOUNT = $_POST['amount']; 
$ogone_QUANTITY = $_POST['quantity']; 

$ogone_AMOUNT = $ogone_AMOUNT*$ogone_QUANTITY;

$ogone_AMOUNT = round($ogone_AMOUNT, 2)*100;
$ogone_CURRENCY = $_POST['currency']; 
$ogone_LANGUAGE = 'en_US'; 

$ogone_ACCEPTURL = $_POST['return'];
$ogone_CANCELURL = $_POST['cancel'];

$ogone_SHASIGN = "ACCEPTURL=$ogone_ACCEPTURL$ogone_SHA". 
"AMOUNT=$ogone_AMOUNT$ogone_SHA".
"CANCELURL=$ogone_CANCELURL$ogone_SHA".
"CURRENCY=$ogone_CURRENCY$ogone_SHA".
"LANGUAGE=$ogone_LANGUAGE$ogone_SHA".
"ORDERID=$ogone_ORDERID$ogone_SHA".
"PSPID=$ogone_PSPID$ogone_SHA";

$ogone_SHASIGN = sha1($ogone_SHASIGN);


$ogone_video_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$ogone_video_name = explode(":",$ogone_video_name);
$ogone_video_name = $ogone_video_name[1];

?>

<form method="post" action="https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/prod/orderstandard.asp" id=form1 name=form1>

        <!-- paramètres généraux : voir Paramètres de formulaire -->
        <input type="hidden" name="PSPID"       value="<?php echo $ogone_PSPID;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="ORDERID"     value="<?php echo $ogone_ORDERID;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT"      value="<?php echo $ogone_AMOUNT;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY"    value="<?php echo $ogone_CURRENCY;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="LANGUAGE"    value="<?php echo $ogone_LANGUAGE;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="CN" value="">  <!-- Le nom du client (facultatif) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="EMAIL" value="">  <!-- L’adresse électronique du client (facultatif) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="OWNERZIP" value="">  <!-- Le code postal du client (facultatif) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="OWNERADDRESS" value="">  <!-- L’adresse du client (facultatif) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="OWNERCTY" value="">  <!-- Le pays du client (facultatif) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="OWNERTOWN" value="">  <!-- Nom de la ville du client (facultatif) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="OWNERTELNO" value="">  <!-- Le numéro de téléphone du client (facultatif) -->

        <!-- vérification avant le paiement : voir Sécurité : vérification avant le paiement (facultatif) -->
        <input type="hidden" name="SHASIGN" value="<?php echo $ogone_SHASIGN;?>">

        <!-- apparence et impression: voir Apparence de la page de paiement -->
        <input type="hidden" name="TITLE" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="BGCOLOR" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="TXTCOLOR" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="TBLBGCOLOR" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="TBLTXTCOLOR" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="BUTTONBGCOLOR" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="BUTTONTXTCOLOR" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="LOGO" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="FONTTYPE" value="">
        <!-- redirection après la transaction : voir Feedback au client sur la transaction -->
        <input type="hidden" name="ACCEPTURL" value="<?php echo $ogone_ACCEPTURL;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="DECLINEURL" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="EXCEPTIONURL" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="<?php echo $ogone_CANCELURL;?>">


    <div class="userpro-section userpro-column userpro-collapsible-1 userpro-collapsed-0"><span><i class="userpro-icon-angle-down"></i></span>Video Details</div>

    <div class='userpro-field userpro-field-first_name ' data-key='first_name'>
         <div class='userpro-label iconed'><label for='first_name-501'>Video Name</label><div class=''></div></div>
         <div class='userpro-input'>
             <b style='color:#090569 !important;font-size: 13px;font-weight:bold'><?php echo  $ogone_video_name;?></b>

                                 <div class='userpro-clear'></div></div></div><div class='userpro-clear'>
    </div>

    <div class='userpro-field userpro-field-first_name ' data-key='first_name'>
         <div class='userpro-label iconed'><label for='first_name-501'>Video Price</label><div class=''></div></div>
         <div class='userpro-input'>
             <b style='color:#090569 !important;font-size: 13px;font-weight:bold'><?php echo  round(number_format(intval($ogone_AMOUNT)/100.00,2),2) . "  " . $ogone_CURRENCY ;?></b>

                                 <div class='userpro-clear'></div></div></div><div class='userpro-clear'>
    </div>  


        <div class="userpro-clear"></div>

                    <div class="userpro-field userpro-submit userpro-column">

            <div class="userpro-social-connect"></div><div class="userpro-clear"></div>             
                            <input type="submit" value="Buy" class="userpro-button" id='ogone-buy'>




            <div class="userpro-clear"></div>

        </div>

<form>
```

i got erros after the payment. this is the picture of the error

[error after ogone payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygbob.jpg)

thank you.